# Is Visual Basic supported by .NET Core on Linux?

Tags: linux, vb.net, yeoman, .net-core

I have searched all Microsoft documentation and I can't find anything that explicitly states whether Visual Basic is supported by .NET Core on Linux. So, does .NET Core on Linux support Visual Basic and is there a yeoman generator for Visual Basic applications?

Comment: it's now supported.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no Visual Basic support yet. At the very bottom of the [roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap) in the "future work" section, it said at one time, that Visual Basic support was set for quarter 3 of 2016, but it is still not released as of March 2017. It is still planned.

Since ASP.NET Core is the most common thing that targets the .NET Core framework, the answer I've provided refers to that.

Comment: That's not quite the same, is it? That refers to **ASP**.NET Core at https://github.com/aspnet/Home - not **.NET** Core at https://github.com/dotnet/core .

Comment: @MichaelRatanapintha Great question. I probably should have addressed that in the answer. .NET Core is the replacement for the .NET 4.6 Framework. It uses the CLR and isn't restricted to any language. You don't use it directly, you use ASP.NET Core (or whatever else they come out with that will use .NET Core like WPF or whatever). This [MSDN Blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/01/19/asp-net-5-is-dead-introducing-asp-net-core-1-0-and-net-core-1-0/) has a nice little diagram. We can't use Visual Basic until Microsoft implements it in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: .NET Core CLI supports command line projects (even w/o ASP.NET Core). Nevertheless, VB is out for the RTM version (https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/72) but planned later. F# seem to be supported immediately, since the F# Community contributed it.

Comment: A microsoft update for 2017 would be appreciated. I actually don't care about VB for .net core but once it's in there, I want to use the commits that add it as a way to study how to add my own language to .net core.

Comment: @rgvassar, .NET Core is not the replacement for the .NET 4.6, never will be. Its cross-platform and modular fork of .NET. Both will go side by side parallel. Though windows only, full .net (4.6.*) has wider API canvas thus drives wider range of app models. Also, both uses their own CLR and .net core support Roslyn(C# and VB) and F# only as opposed to full .net, it does support dozens including above.

Comment: I just checked and VIsual Studio 2017 shipped WITHOUT this feature.

Comment: @WarrenP That's a good point. I should have said .Net Core is the latest framework. It doesn't include a lot of features like WPF, so it can't replace 4.6 for a lot of use cases.

Answer (score 4):

**Visual Basic *is supported*** by [.NET Core](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-net-core-2-0/) starting with [.NET Core 2.0 Preview 1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/05/10/announcing-net-core-2-0-preview-1/).

Comment: Not fully. Only console and library applications supported.  Perhaps in 2018 there will be full support.

Comment: The .NET Core 3 preview in VS2019 supports VB in Console, WPF, WinForms etc.  Also check here "https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vbteam/2017/06/13/visual-basic-and-cross-platform-mobile-apps-with-vb-xamarin-and-net-standard/" for VS2017.