# ASP.NET project with VS Code and using npm-lite for local server

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, npm, visual-studio-code

I have a VB ASP.NET project that I'm trying to setup on my Mac.  VS Code is a version of Visual Studio that works on the Mac so this SHOULD work...

The problem is that it doesn't have any local server, no IIS or anything.

I found [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdndevs/2016/01/24/visual-studio-code-and-local-web-server/) that says hey, just use npm to make a local server.

I did all the steps of installing node and npm, but when I run `npm start`, when it opens http://localhost:3000/ in the browser, the page just says `Cannot GET /` on a blank page.

I notice in the post I linked to, it says "(assuming you have an index.html)".  This project has default.aspx instead; how do I indicate that?

Since npm-lite is the server it seems like there should be a way to tell it what the start file is.  I've been looking [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lite-server#custom-configuration) and [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) but can't figure it out so far.

1. How do I tell npm-lite that when I go to localhost:3000/ that should load up the Default.aspx file?
2. Is there anything else that I'm doing wrong, or anything else I should know about if I'm trying to get npm and npm-lite to work as my web server for a ASP.NET project?

Comment: The article you linked to is talking about serving up **static** files, not running ASP.NET. It's a different problem. You need to compile and execute your application. Are you using .NET Core?

Comment: @NateBarbettini I am using .NET Core.  When I run `dotnet run` in the root directory I get `object reference not set to an instance of an object`.  I know I have it installed because `dotnet --help` shows all the dotnet commands, including run.  So not sure what's up here.

Comment: I notice that when I create a test app with dotnet, it has Program.cs and project.json files in it, whereas my project doesn't have those...so I'm assuming at this point it has something to do with that, but not sure what conventions to use for writing those files.

Comment: Yes, you need project.json to compile a .NET Core project. Try using `dotnet new` to scaffold a new project. However, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35639679/is-visual-basic-supported-on-net-core-on-linux

Comment: Ah!  Apparently VB is not supported for .NET Core yet.  Thanks so much for that link.

Comment: Guess I might as well make it an answer in case someone else comes looking for it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Basic is [not yet supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35639679/is-visual-basic-supported-on-net-core-on-linux) on .NET Core.

See the Future Work section of the [ASP.NET Core roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap#future-work):

> The following features unfortunately won't make it into the initial RTM release. We are tentatively planning on shipping them in the initial feature release after RTM, during Q3* of 2016:
>
> - Visual Basic support

Once it's supported, you'll be able to start up your project by simply executing `dotnet run` inside your project folder. That'll start up the web server defined in your `Startup.cs` file and allow you to browse the site locally.